# Deno Compile - Still not compiled after 24 hours

Tags: deno

So I need to bundle my Deno application for easier distribution.

I ran the compiler using the below

`deno compile --allow-read --allow-write --allow-run ./lib/cli.ts`

I left the process running for 24 hours and the CLI output hasn't changed from

```
Check file:///Users/[user]/Workspace/app/lib/cli.ts
Bundle file:///Users/[user]/Workspace/app/lib/cli.ts
```

Now this is running on OS X - Big Sur and the Macbook did lock itself after an hour so I'm suspicious that this may have caused a complete lock of the deno process...however upon research, OS X going into "Lock" state shouldn't prevent processe's from functioning as expected.

Is this the case? or is something else going on?

Bare in mind the Source Code is about 8mb in size, I understand that `deno compile` wraps the app in `deno` + `v8` to ensure the binary is self-executable.

However, I'm still left asking myself the question...is this expected behavior?

---

Update: I've re-ran with the debug log level, currently it's been stuck at

```
DEBUG RS - swc_bundler::bundler::chunk::merge:402 - All modules are merged
DEBUG RS - swc_bundler::inline:23 - Inlining injected variables
DEBUG RS - swc_bundler::modules::sort:29 - Sorting ModuleId(0)
DEBUG RS - swc_bundler::modules::sort::chunk:75 - Topologically sorting modules based on the dependency graph: (388 items)
```

for 15 minutes so far, will update if this changes.

Answer (score 1):

The [issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/8224) has been fixed as of `deno 1.12.0`. So upgrading to the latest version (`deno upgrade`) might solve the issue for you.